Are parabolic Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials truncations of the usual Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials?
Let $(W,S)$ be the affine Weyl group associated to a simple root system.
For $x,y \in W$ we have the usual Kazhdan--Lustig polynomials $h_{y,x} \in \mathbb{Z}[v]$ in Soergel's normalisation, and if both $x,y$ correspond to alcoves in the dominant cone then we also have the parabolic Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials $n_{y,x}$ defined by Deodhar, again in Soergel's normalisation.
Deodhar has shown how to express the parabolic Kazhdan--Lusztig polynomials in terms of the usual ones---it is a signed sum over the finite Weyl group---but I would like to know something a bit different. The precise question is:

For $x,y \in W$ corresponding to alcoves in the dominant cone, does $h_{y,x} - n_{y,x} \in \mathbb{Z}[v]$ have non-negative coefficients and is the degree of the smallest monomial occurring in it (with non-zero coefficient) greater than the degree of $n_{y,x}$?

I would be happy with "greater than or equal" instead of "greater than".
I am a novice in this area, so I apologize if this is well-known or easy. It seems to be true in many examples in all rank $2$ types, but I do not know a proof in the general rank $2$ case. (My main interest is when $y = e$, but I don't see how to use this assumption.)
If the answer to the question is not known, I would also appreciate  heuristic arguments regarding whether or not the answer is likely to be positive.
(Soergel's article can be found here.)
Edit: Geordie Williamson has given a positive answer to the first part of the question which I have accepted because of the bounty since there are no other answers so far. I am still interested in knowing the answer to the second part.

Deodhar has two versions of the parabolic polynomials: the "u=q" and "u=-1" versions. Do you know which you care about?

@ChristianGaetz: I am interested in the polynomials in Theorem 3.1 (2.) of Soergel's paper that I have linked to. The precise relation with Deodhar's polynomials is given in Bemerkungen 3.2, but the short answer to your question is that I care about the "u=q" parabolic polynomials.

p.s. A version of Soergel's article in English can be found here.

A quick answer for which standard health warnings apply.
For your first question, the answer is positive, as follows (for example) from my paper with Libedinsky here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00459
Very rough sketch of proof: the anti-spherical category is a quotient of the Hecke category (homotopy category of Soergel bimodules). The KL polynomial $h_{y,x}$ is graded rank of hom in the Hecke category, and $n_{y,x}$ is graded rank of hom in the anti-spherical category. In quotient category the hom space can only get smaller, hence $h_{y,x} - n_{y,x}$ has non-negative coefficients (it is the graded rank of some kernel of a map of graded vector spaces).
(Much of these ideas come from Lusztig and Bezrukavnikov, and you could probably find proofs in their work. Arkhipov-Bezrukavnikov was certainly a major inspiration for the work above.)
I don't know the answer to your second question. It seems quite strong, but I had a look at a few examples and didn't find a counter-example.

Thanks! My original motivation for the question was to compute $n_{e,x}$, for $x$ a Duflo involution in the dominant cone, using Lusztig's result about $h_{e,x}$, but then looking at examples it seemed that a more general statement might be true.

In earlier versions of your answer you had expressed skepticism about the second part of the question, if you still feel that way perhaps you could include that in the answer since I will accept it soon. But note that my question is only about affine Weyl groups, not general Coxeter groups as in your paper with Libedinsky.
